# How to notify property change for count of an ObservableCollection in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

Let, I have an `ObservableCollection`. I m binding it's Count property with the Text property of a `TextBlock`. As one or more items added or deleted from the collection the Count get updated. As I know `ObservableCollection` implements both the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so when the Count property is changed then my view should be updated. I am expecting the `TextBlock` that is bind with the Count property should show the updated count. But anyhow `NotifyPropertyChange` is not being called for the Count property!

Here how I am binding the Text property with Count:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyObservableCollection.Count}" />
```

Is there any way to notify property change for the Count property of an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this Issue. Check your property and Datacontext.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way is to use  CollectionChanged eventhandler
For example:

```
 public class ViewModelExample : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int _count;
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _count;
        }
        set
        {
            _count = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Count");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<String> _myObservableCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<String> MyObservableCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _myObservableCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _myObservableCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyObservableCollection");
        }
    }

    public ViewModelExample()
    {
        this.MyObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<String>();
        this.MyObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
        this.Count = MyObservableCollection.Count;
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            this.MyObservableCollection.Add("SOMETHING HERE");
        }
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.NewItems!=null)
        {
           this.Count+=e.NewItems.Count;
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

YOUR XAML

```
 <TextBlock FontSize="30">
            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                <Run Text="CURRENT COUNT="/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Count,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </TextBlock.Inlines>
        </TextBlock>
```

AND THEN YOU WILL GET THE FOLLOWING RESULT :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

other way:

you can add a Count to your view model, when you add or remove item from MyObservableCollection, you update Count manual, and invoke NotifyPropertyChange.

Answer (score 0):

As For as I know `ObservableCollection` will update automatically in the cases of Add/Remove if you are Set a new value for entire `ObservableCollection` means you need to Raise the `ObservableCollection` in the setter of the property. So if you are setting new collection means add `PropertyChangedEvent` and if you are doing add/remove means don't need to Raise the property.If you are in second scenario Check your output window for Binding errors most probably that will be your problem.